# minimal hardware configuration for TFS

Tags: team-foundation-server

I wish I have Team Foundation Server 2010. What is the most minimal hardware configuration to handle this? there will be only few solution stored for at most 10 people who will be rarely working on this at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Really? Is Google that difficult to use?

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-foundation-server/system-requirements

Comment: Seems so. MS usually has some pretty good docs for their products.

Answer (score 0):

**Basic Configuration**

- PC with a 2.2-GHz or faster processor
- 1 GB RAM
- 8 GB of available hard disk space
- Windows Vista® operating system with Service Pack 2 (both 32-bit and 64-bit versions, excluding Windows Vista Starter and Home Basic Editions)
- Windows 7® operating system (both 32-bit and 64-bit versions, excluding Windows 7 Starter Edition)
- Windows Server® 2003 (32-bit) with Service Pack 2 or later (all editions)
- Windows Server® 2003 R2 (32-bit) or later (all editions)
- Windows Server® 2008 (both 32-bit and 64-bit) with Service Pack 2 or later
- Windows Server® 2008 R2 (64-bit)

**Advanced Configuration**

- PC with a 2.2-GHz or faster processor
- 2 GB RAM
- 8 GB of available hard disk space
- Windows Server® 2003 (32-bit) with Service Pack 2 or later (all editions)
- Windows Server® 2003 R2 (32-bit) or later (all editions)
- Windows Server® 2008 (both 32-bit and 64-bit) with Service Pack 2 or later
- Windows Server® 2008 R2 (64-bit)

**Note:** Basic configuration and client operating systems do not support integration with SharePoint products or the reporting feature. If you want to use either one of these features, you must install Team Foundation Server on a server operating system

[Source](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-foundation-server/system-requirements)